# Installing NET Framework on XP

Tags: .net

I have a computer with XP Pro, and want it to work with NET Framework 2.0 and later. However I'm unsure what to actually install..

Looking at this page for NET 2.0:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa731542.aspx

Do I need to download both the redistributable version, and ALSO the 2.0 SP2 package?

Also the same question valid for 3.5 download from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc378097.aspx

If I later find out I need NET 1.1, will that be ok to install after all the later NET Frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to install .NET 3.5 any application written for another lower version will work.
You don't need to install .net 2.0 or 1.1 later.

Generally if you install .NET 4.0 you should be able to run any proram written for a lower version. However there might be problems and this might not always be true in the case of .net 4.0. [Check this out for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx).

Comment: Ok, so this is true if installing 3.5 SP1, but not for 4.0 ?

Comment: Any version of .NET will be compatible with applications wirtten for lower versions but not vice versa.

Comment: well, I thought so initially, and installed 4.0. But it failed to run programs and requested 3.5. Did I install wrong? I believe I used the "Install Now" on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're probably best downloading the [3.5 SP1 full package](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe) if you're going to be installing on more than one machine - this includes all the .net 1.0, .net 2.0 (SP2) etc stuff

Comment: I'm only going to install on one laptop. I'm still confused. "Full package" what does it mean. Is it different from clicking the "install now" button for 3.5 SP1 on this page? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc378097.aspx

Comment: or is it the same, just that it's a download, not direct install?

Answer (score 1):

Just download .NET 3.5 SP1, it covers all the previous service packs and security updates.  The download [is here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en).  This gets you a small bootstrapper that then figures out what additional updates need to be installed on your machine.  The amount of time this will take is quite unpredictable.  It could take quite a while (hundreds of megabytes) if you haven't used Windows Update to keep your machine up to date.

You definitely ought to consider downloading the free Express edition of Visual Studio for the language that you are interested in.  This will get you going a *lot* quicker.  The current edition for the Express version is VS2010, it will actually install .NET 4.0 on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

it's easier to install them from web platform installer
http://www.microsoft.com/web/

Comment: Using the web platform installer is fantastic if you wish to develop web applications. But is overkill if you are simply developing desktop applications etc.